# Unresolved external symbol - LNK2019 from C++ dll

Tags: c++, dll, calling-convention, unresolved-external

I load a GetInstance function from a C++ dll with GetProcAddress to my base code and get
some Unresolved external symbol errors:

> error **LNK2019**: unresolved external symbol "_*declspec(dllimport)
>   public: unsigned int* _thiscall
>   RegTestAPI::CTestmode_Sle70::SetMSfr(unsigned int,unsigned short,char
>   *)" (_*imp*?SetMSfr@CTestmode_Sle70@RegTestAPI@@QAEIIGPAD@Z) referenced in function "int **__cdecl** SetUserDescriptor(unsigned
>   char,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?SetUserDescriptor@@YAHEII@Z)

**DLL code**

header

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) CTestmode* GetInstance();
```

source

```
CTestmode *cTestmode;

extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) CTestmode* GetInstance()
{
    cTestmode = CTestmode::Instance();

    return cTestmode;
}
```

...

```
// in header
static CTestmode* Instance();
... 
static CTestmode* m_pInstance;

// in source
CTestmode* CTestmode::Instance()
{
    if(m_pInstance == NULL)
    {   
        m_pInstance = new CTestmode();
    }

    return m_pInstance;
}
```

**Tool code**

```
typedef CTestmode* (*CTestModeInstance)(void);

CTestmode *pMyTM;

...

HMODULE handleTestmode;
handleTestmode = LoadLibrary("Testmode.dll");

CTestModeInstance cTestModeInstance = (CTestModeInstance)GetProcAddress(handleTestmode, "GetInstance");

pMyTM = (cTestModeInstance)();
```

My idea is that something with the calling conventions are wrong (look at the error message -> __thiscall and __cdecl Hint: both projects are set to __cdecl (/Gd)) ?!

Any ideas why this won't work?

Thank you in advance!

greets

Comment: Instead of all the posted code we need the code of `SetUserDescriptor`, and declaration and definition of `CTestmode_Sle70::SetMSfr`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is not easy to read, but it is self-explanatory. Function `CTestmode_Sle70::SetMSfr` is referenced in function `SetUserDescriptor`, but it's not defined anywhere. Linker can't bind a call to `SetMSfr` because the function does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an implementation for `SetMSfr(unsigned int,unsigned short,char *);`